# rm no such file or directory terminal

Tags: rm

I have tried --force, it doesn't work. When I put in sudo rm -d /someplace/wanttodelete it says: rm: cannot remove '/someplace/wanttodelete': No such file or directory

There is a directory, I can cd  into it. I don't understand what is going wrong. I'm trying to remove some folders from a PHPBB install so I can upgrade my current forum.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: When you are in that directory that you are trying to delete, type in `pwd` and it will show you the entire path to that folder.  Then you can leave that folder and then do the `rm` command on that entire path to that folder.

Comment: I was in the folder and tired pwd it said the folder but I left the folder and tried to remove it again and it still gave me a no such file or directory.

Comment: To remove the folder if it is not empty the actual command is `rm -rf /path/to/folder`  If the folder is empty, then the command is `rmdir /path/to/folder`